# Dockerized Django REST Framework / Postgresql - Disallowed host

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

When I try to execute the following command:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

I get the following error inside my terminal:

[image]

Here is what my docker file looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /agent-technologies
WORKDIR /agent-technologies
COPY . /agent-technologies 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
```

Here is what my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=stefan_radonjic
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=cepajecar995
      - POSTGRES_DB=agent_technologies_db
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/agent-technologies
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And finally here are settings of PostgresSQL DB I have previously created :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'agent_technologies_db',
        'USER': 'stefan_radonjic',
        'PASSWORD': 'cepajecar995',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Host of your database in DATABASES dict should be "db"

Comment: thank you this actually fixed my issue but now i have new problem. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite self explanatory.. You didn't set your ip in your [ALLOWED_HOSTS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts). Try adding these to your settings file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # wildcard, allows all
```

Or if you want to be explicit:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0'] # explicit
```

Answer (score 1):

Your django app is trying to connect to 'localhost' database, but as it is inside its own container -- localhost is not right uri to reach database.

Dockercompose will resolve your namequeries to database if you will refer to is by db container name. In your case it is "db"

As text on picture reads -- you have to add "0.0.0.0" into your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`  variable inside your settings module.

Be sure that you've read django documentation carefully. It is pretty vigorous.

Comment: Thank you guys, this has fixed my problem!